# Cross-project PubSub subscription via IAM ServiceAccount

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have two projects Project-A and Project-B.

On Project-A I have a service account `loader@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com` which I want to use to read messages from Project-B PubSub topic.

I've created a topic subscription on Project-B `projects/project-b/subscriptions/data`. Then added `loader@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com` in Permissions tab as a `Subscriber`. I believe it should give me access.

But if I try:

```
TestIamPermissionsRequest iamreq = new TestIamPermissionsRequest();
iamreq.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(
        "pubsub.subscriptions.consume",
        "pubsub.subscriptions.get"
));
pubsub.projects().subscriptions()
        .testIamPermissions(topicSubscription, iamreq).execute();
```

It returns empty list of permissions.

And for actual pull request:

```
PullRequest pull = new PullRequest();
pull.setMaxMessages(1);
pull.setReturnImmediately(true);
pubsub.projects().subscriptions().pull(topicSubsription, pull).execute();
```

It fails with:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "User not authorized to perform this action.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "User not authorized to perform this action.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I've double checked that service account is in Subscribers list, also tried to remove/add it again, etc. Tried with different project. It doesn't change anything.

If I have PubSub Topic Subscription and Service Account under same Cloud Project, then it works fine, for both `testIamPermissions` and `pull` requests. Does it mean that IAM Service Account cannot be used to get access to PubSub from another project?

Please note that it works fine for Storage access from other project. Which means that problem is specific only to PubSub. That's why I think I've missed something on PubSub configuration side. But what exactly?

Comment: It seem that Cloud Console is broken. Because if I add Subscriber permission directly through API it works as expected (still investigating...)

Comment: Seems like you're calling `pubsub.projects().subscriptions().testIamPermissions` against a topic, which seems incorrect.

Comment: it's correct topic subscription, in form `projects/%xxx%/subscriptions/%yyyy%`. Client lib throws different exception if i'll try to pass invalid value there

Comment: Ok, then why the variable name is `topic`?

Comment: because it's topic's subscription, how I should call it? maybe i'm old fashioned guy, but it was always "topic" in every other Message Queue system. So I keep calling it "topic", sometimes it's hard to change your habbits

Comment: The topics and subscriptions are different resources with Cloud Pub/Sub. I would call it a subscription.

Comment: does it really matter?

Comment: It confuses people trying to answer your question :)

Comment: ok, i've changed as you suggested. but it didn't fix actual issue unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

To consume from Topic Subscription role "Subscriber" should be given to the Subscription. Unfortunately it's not possible with Cloud Console right now.

The problem was that Cloud Console is misleading, by selecting a Topic I expect to setup permissions to Topic Subscriptions also (because there're no separate UI for Topic Subscriptions after all). But it's doesn't work like this, Permissions form applies changes *only* to selected Topic, ignoring all existing Topic subscriptions. Basically you cannot view or edit Subscriber permissions, there're no such UI currently.

*PS There're a way to do that via API, though. But it doesn't work for my situation*